# function WP_Widget::widget() must be over-ridden in a sub-class. when create new Widget

Tags: widgets

Show: function WP_Widget::widget() must be over-ridden in a sub-class. in website.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The class that extends `WP_Widget` must have a `widget` method. That is:

```
class Dummy_Widget extends WP_Widget {

  /* This method is required */
  function widget($args, $instance) {

  }

}
```